# I am fetching database data and and converting it to a pdf file. But not getting the correct output

Tags: php, mysqli, mpdf

this is my code to get data from the database and then output the data in the pdf file. i am getting an error as shown in the image attatched. kindly help in resolving this error.

```
 <?php


 $db= mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','guests') or die("error 
 connecting to mysqli server");  require_once __DIR__ . 
 '/vendor/autoload.php';


 $str = 'abcd'; $html=array(); $sql = 'SELECT * FROM  data';   
 //mysqli_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'"); $req = mysqli_query($db,$sql) or 
 die('Error SQL!'.$sql.'<br>'.mysqli_error());   

 ob_start()

 $mpdf=new mPDF(); 

  //ob_start();    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($req)){  
  //ob_start();
  // $name = $row['name'];
  // $phone=$row['phone'];
  // $status=$row['status'];
  // //$html .='<div class="form-group">'.$name.'</div>'.'<div 
 class="form-group">'.$phone.'</div>'.'<div class="form-
 group">'.$status.'</div>';
 $html[]=$row;

    foreach ($html as $row ) {
        # code...
        //echo $row['name'];
        //var_dump($html);
        print_r(array_values($html));
        //die();
        $mpdf->AddPage('L','','','','',50,50,50,50,10,10);


        $str= $str. ob_get_contents();
        $mpdf->WriteHTML($str);
        //break;
    }
   //$mpdf->WriteHTML($html);


  //$mpdf->WriteHTML($content); } // var_dump($str); // die(); //$mpdf-
 >WriteHTML($str);

 ob_end_clean();

 $mpdf->Output('pdf.pdf','I');

 ?>
```

its showing me the error as
[image]

Comment: The error message is quite clear. Your settings has a max execution time of 30 seconds and this script takes longer. Try to set it to a higher value. Add this to the top of your script: `ini_set('max_execution_time', 60);` where `60` is 60 seconds (change it if you need to). Read more about [`ini_set()` in the manua](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ini-set.php)l.

Comment: you also have a syntax error; highlighting's showing you.

Comment: ini_set('max_execution_time', 300);   Add this Line ....

Comment: Theirs no need to configure your execution. Just theirs a conflict between you codes that's why it show a execution time error. Try to review every closing tags you have because that's the root cause of your error.

Answer (score 0):

```
`ini_set('max_execution_time', 300); //300 seconds = 5 minute
```

**Place this at the top of your PHP script and let your script !!**

if your PHP setup is running in `safe mode`, you can only change it from the **php.ini file.**

**OR**

Use This

```
set_time_limit(0);
```

Comment: http://www.steptoinstall.com/fatal-error-maximum-execution-time-30-seconds-exceeded-wordpress.html